# Find the center of circle $P$ and $Q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

Given that circle $P : Center(a,b)$  has a radius of $r_1$, circle $ Q : Center(c,d)$ has a radius of $r_2$. Circle $P$ and circle $Q$ intersects at point $A = (3,8)$ and $B = (3,-4)$ when $r_2=\frac{2}3r_1$.

If $$a,b,c,d \subseteq  \mathbb Z$$ when $$30 \lt 3c-2a \lt 40$$

Q : Find the center of circle $P$ and $Q$.

I have determined the pythagoras triangle between two circles;
$$a_1=6,b_1=|3-a|,c_1=r_1$$ and
$$a_2=6,b_2=|3-c|,c_2=\frac{2}3*r_1$$
Which using one of the many circle properties, I come up with
$$|3-a|=|3-c|$$ which i couldn’t progress further.

Help me solve the problem anew or continue with my solution.

Comment: Is $I$ meant to be the irrational numbers ($\Bbb R - \Bbb Q$) or the integers ($\Bbb Z$)?

Comment: $$r_1^2=(a-3)^2+(b+4)^2=(a-3)^2+(b-8)^2$$

$\implies b=2,r_1^2=(a-3)^2+(2+4)^2$

As $(3,8)$ is on $P,r_1^2=(3-3)^2+6^2\implies r_1=6$

So, if the equation of $P$ is $$(x-a)^2+(y-2)^2=6^2$$

and $(3,8)$ lies on $P,a=3$

Comment: a subset I is meaninglesx.

Comment: $I$ stands for integer in my country.

Comment: so $a,b,c,d \subseteq \mathbb Z$ if written in international rules.

Comment: Irrational in my country is represented by $Q’$

Comment: @kornkaobat.  What international rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
I will not hesitate to put that into mathjax though.
For reference only.